# How do I split sitemaps with Django (programatically)?

Tags: python, django, sitemap

Although the Google sitemap limit is 50k urls, I want to split my sitemap to some with 500 urls.

This is the Blog Sitemap,

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from blog.models import Entry

class BlogSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "never"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Entry.objects.all()[:500]


    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.pub_date
```

The URL configuration

```
from blog.sitemaps import BlogSitemap


sitemaps = {
    'blog': BlogSitemap
}
```

and

```
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
        name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')
```

The database model has more than 500 objects, how do I split the sitemap so that it can be accessed by sitemap1.xml, sitemap2.xml, etc automatically even if there are 5000 objects?

thanks.

ps. I want a programmatic solution.

pps. Its okay retrieving objects without filters. Can use primary keys (1-500), (500-1000) etc. thanks

Comment: I believe if you set the `limit` attribute in your sitemap class, django will automatically paginate your sitemap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sitemap limit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.limit):

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap

class LimitSitemap(Sitemap):
    limit = 500

class BlogSitemap(LimitSitemap):
    def items(self):
        return Entry.objects.all()
```